# Excel 2016: VBA: Formula throws syntax error in a Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have Excel data with column F that has date/time in the format: 11/13/2018  9:33:00 PM
Now, I need to get that date displayed in column H as per the formula `=TEXT(F2,("MMM-dd"))`
(I currently do this manually which works fine)

The VBA seems to work up until it hits this formula where it throws me the error: `Compile Error Syntax Error`

Rest of the code works as expected. I have tried alternate formulas and they seem to work. For example, if I use 
`rng.Value = "words"` or
`rng.Formula = "2+2"`
the macro works as expected

Code that won't compile:

---

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("H2:H" & Lastrow)
rng.Formula = "=TEXT(F2,("MMM-dd"))"

End Sub
```

---

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm new to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jhqLXvNq for the VBA code

Post format got weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extra quotation marks:

```
"=TEXT(F2,(""MMM-dd""))"
```

Here's the official help, [Quotation marks in string expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions).

Comment: This seems to have been the problem, thank you!!!

Comment: @Dave please use the green checkmark to indicate that the post answered your question.